# How to sync google public calendar?

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar

Recently, My project requires me to sync google calendar. They really concern about GDPR and user privacy. Therefore, I come up with a solution to sync user's google public calendar which does not require any authentication at all and only get the Busy/Free schedule of user.

The problem I am facing is that I can not find any google API to get sync the public calendar. I also did research iCalendar which google will return all of user's public calendar in .ics extension, but it can not be filtered at all.

The Question I asked is that:

1. Does google have any API for syncing public calendar?
2. Can do I filtering on .ics file from google?
3. Are there any ways to sync user public calendar from google?